# Can lightning bring down a plane?

Tags: physics, aviation

Some [early reports](http://www.news.com.au/travel/travel-updates/air-algerie-plane-wreckage-remains-found-in-mali-after-crashing-in-rainstorm/story-fnizu68q-1227000625288) by witnesses to the [Air Algérie Flight 5017](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Alg%C3%A9rie_Flight_5017) crash claim that lightning caused the plane to crash:

> A GROUP of herders who say they saw Air Algerie flight AH5017 crash claim it went down after being struck by lightning, local officials told Reuters.
>   Louis Berthaud, a community counsellor in Gossi near where the plane carrying 116 people went down, said: “The herders were in the bush and saw the plane fall.”
>   He added: “It must have been a storm and it was struck by lightning. They said it was on fire as it fell, before it crashed.”

I have done a lot of research before I read this article. I know that planes are made of metals that are good conductors of electricity. From what I know, this means that the electricity will flow 'around' the outside of the plane and is essentially a [Faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_cage). That means that the lightning itself won't be able affect the plane except for scorches on the outside.

Can lightning ignite a fuselage or bring down a plane?

Comment: Careful: the witnesses are apparently saying they saw the plane struck by lightning. They are not asserting that lightning was the cause of the crash.

Comment: I don't know about *igniting a fuselage*, but it can play hell with electrical systems. I worked avionics for ten years, and after any reported lightning strike we had a lengthy checklist of problems to look for. A system failure resulting in a crash sounds very plausible, at least to me.

Comment: Do a google image search for "plane lightning damage" and look at the images and judge yourself if those damages provide a possiblity (not a necessity) for a plane to come down. Especially intresting is one image of a twisted tube *inside* the plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It is possible**, however unlikely in modern commercial aircraft.

Some of past incidents:

- 1963 – [Pan Am Flight 214](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_Flight_214), was hit by lightning igniting the fuel. Crashed killing everyone onboard (81 people).
- 1973 – crash of an Ozark Airlines Fairchild FH227B in St. Louis, which killed 38 and injured six passengers and crew. A lightning strike on final approach was cited as a probable cause.
- 1985 – crash of a Delta Air Lines Lockheed L-1011-385 in Dallas/Fort Worth, which killed 135 and injured 30 passengers and crew. Lighting was cited as a contributing factor.

How can it happen:

> **Lightning Effects**
>
> Both the occupants of an aircraft and the aircraft itself are subject
>   to the powerful effects of a lightning strike. The inherent structural
>   design of an aircraft provides the occupants almost complete
>   protection despite the massive amount of current involved. This
>   protection is based on the principle known as the Faraday cage, first
>   devised by the physicist Michael Faraday in 1836.
>
> A Faraday cage is a hollow enclosure made of conducting material, such
>   as the hull of an aircraft. In the presence of a strong electric
>   field, any electric charge will be forced to redistribute itself on
>   the outside enclosure, but the space inside the cage remains
>   uncharged. Thus, the metal hull of the aircraft acts as a Faraday
>   cage, protecting the occupants from lightning.
>
> Some aircraft are made of advanced composite materials, which — by
>   themselves — are significantly less conductive than metal. To overcome
>   this resulting safety problem, a layer of conductive fibers or screens
>   is imbedded between layers of the composite material to conduct the
>   lightning current.
>
> Regardless of hull material, the direct effects of lightning on the
>   exterior can also include:
>
> - Burning or melting at lightning strike points;
> - Increase in temperature;
> - Residual magnetism;
> - Acoustic shock effects;
> - Arcing at hinges, joints and bonding points; and,
> - Ignition of fuel vapors.
>
> Accident data indicate that most of these effects are not serious.
>   However, an estimated one-third to one-half of aircraft lightning
>   strikes result in at least some minor damage. Lightning generally
>   enters an aircraft at one location, usually an extremity, and leaves
>   at another.
>
> Burn marks are found at the entry and exit point(s) of the strike,
>   although exit points are not present if the energy was dissipated via
>   wicks or rods — static dischargers whose primary purpose is to bleed
>   off into the surrounding air the static charge build-up that occurs
>   during normal flight.
>
> Because many aircraft fly a distance equivalent to several times their
>   own lengths during a lightning discharge, the location of the entry
>   point can change as the discharge attaches to additional points aft of
>   the initial entry point. The location of the exit points may also
>   change.
>
> Therefore, for any one strike, there may be several entry or exit
>   points.
>
> Occasionally, in more severe strikes, electrical equipment or avionics
>   may be affected or damaged. This potential problem is addressed in
>   modern aircraft design by redundancy. The functions of most critical
>   systems are duplicated, so a lightning strike is unlikely to
>   compromise safety of flight. In most strike events, pilots report
>   nothing more than a temporary flickering of lights or short-lived
>   interference with instruments.
>
> The exception is the incidence of positive lightning. Positive
>   lightning strikes — because of their greater power — are considerably
>   more dangerous than negative lightning strikes. Few aircraft are
>   designed to withstand such strikes without significant damage.

*source [Flight Safety Foundation „When Lightning Strikes”](http://flightsafety.org/aerosafety-world-magazine/june-2010/when-lightning-strikes)*